# Python: debugging with gdb (on OSX)

Tags: python, macos, debugging, gdb

There are quite a few tutorials on debugging with gdb for Python. 
Just to name a few among the best:

- https://wiki.python.org/moin/DebuggingWithGdb
- https://stripe.com/blog/exploring-python-using-gdb
- http://scipy-lectures.github.io/advanced/debugging/#debugging-segmentation-faults-using-gdb

However all of them are targeted for the Linux OS.
Is it feasible to install all the extension packages required on OSX ?

Answer (score 4):

You need to build gdb.  Per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19370703/834250), you need to set `CFLAGS=-Wno-string-plus-int` before building (at least, for MacOS 10.9 and gdb 7.6.1).

You have to [codesign gdb](http://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/BuildingOnDarwin) before you can use it.

Then you need get a 'real' executable out of the MacOS fat binary so gdb can read it:

```
lipo -thin x86_64 -output python-x86_64 /usr/bin/python
```

Then you can happily:

```
gdb --args /path/to/python-x86_64 myPythonScript.py arg1 arg2
```

---

Alternatively, you can use `lldb`.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, it is feasible.  You presumably already have Python for your platform.  Now you just need to build gdb.  gdb isn't as well-supported there, but it does work.

Alternatively you can read the section "GDB on Legacy systems" at that first link.

Comment: Yes, but how do you add the Python extensions for gdb? is there a configure flag that needs to be set when building gdb? Some extra download?