# Error while running make on gdb 7.6 on my mac

Tags: gdb

I am hitting the following errors which I run make for gdb . 
This is after running configure on my mac running OS X 10.8.5 with i7 inter processor.

### gcc version is

```
$ gcc -v
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --withgxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.76) (based on LLVM 3.3svn    
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0
Thread model: posix
```

### Error:

```
/Users/sbala/Downloads/gdb-7.6/opcodes/i386-dis.c:12078:18: error: adding 'char' to a string does not append to the string [-Werror,-Wstring-plus-int]
  oappend ("%st" + intel_syntax);
           ~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/sbala/Downloads/gdb-7.6/opcodes/i386-dis.c:12078:18: note: use array indexing to silence this warning
  oappend ("%st" + intel_syntax);
                 ^
           &     [             ]
/Users/sbala/Downloads/gdb-7.6/opcodes/i386-dis.c:12609:23: error: adding 'char' to a string does not append to the string [-Werror,-Wstring-plus-int]
      oappend ("%cs:" + intel_syntax);
               ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/sbala/Downloads/gdb-7.6/opcodes/i386-dis.c:12609:23: note: use array indexing to silence this warning
      oappend ("%cs:" + intel_syntax);
                      ^
               &      [             ]
/Users/sbala/Downloads/gdb-7.6/opcodes/i386-dis.c:12614:23: error: adding 'char' to a string does not append to the string [-Werror,-Wstring-plus-int]
      oappend ("%ds:" + intel_syntax);
               ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/sbala/Downloads/gdb-7.6/opcodes/i386-dis.c:12614:23: note: use array indexing to silence this warning
      oappend ("%ds:" + intel_syntax);
                      ^
               &      [             ]
/Users/sbala/Downloads/gdb-7.6/opcodes/i386-dis.c:12619:23: error: adding 'char' to a string does not append to the string [-Werror,-Wstring-plus-int]
      oappend ("%ss:" + intel_syntax);
               ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/sbala/Downloads/gdb-7.6/opcodes/i386-dis.c:12619:23: note: use array indexing to silence this warning
      oappend ("%ss:" + intel_syntax);
                      ^
               &      [             ]
/Users/sbala/Downloads/gdb-7.6/opcodes/i386-dis.c:12624:23: error: adding 'char' to a string does not append to the string [-Werror,-Wstring-plus-int]
      oappend ("%es:" + intel_syntax);
               ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/sbala/Downloads/gdb-7.6/opcodes/i386-dis.c:12624:23: note: use array indexing to silence this warning
      oappend ("%es:" + intel_syntax);
                      ^
               &      [             ]
/Users/sbala/Downloads/gdb-7.6/opcodes/i386-dis.c:12629:23: error: adding 'char' to a string does not append to the string [-Werror,-Wstring-plus-int]
      oappend ("%fs:" + intel_syntax);
               ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/sbala/Downloads/gdb-7.6/opcodes/i386-dis.c:12629:23: note: use array indexing to silence this warning
      oappend ("%fs:" + intel_syntax);
                      ^
               &      [             ]
/Users/sbala/Downloads/gdb-7.6/opcodes/i386-dis.c:12634:23: error: adding 'char' to a string does not append to the string [-Werror,-Wstring-plus-int]
      oappend ("%gs:" + intel_syntax);
               ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/sbala/Downloads/gdb-7.6/opcodes/i386-dis.c:12634:23: note: use array indexing to silence this warning
      oappend ("%gs:" + intel_syntax);
                      ^
               &      [             ]
/Users/sbala/Downloads/gdb-7.6/opcodes/i386-dis.c:13973:19: error: adding 'char' to a string does not append to the string [-Werror,-Wstring-plus-int]
  oappend ("%es:" + intel_syntax);
           ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/sbala/Downloads/gdb-7.6/opcodes/i386-dis.c:13973:19: note: use array indexing to silence this warning
  oappend ("%es:" + intel_syntax);
                  ^
           &      [             ]
8 errors generated.
make[4]: *** [i386-dis.lo] Error 1
make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [all-opcodes] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2"
```

Let me know if you need more details.

Answer (score 6):

It looks like --enable-werror is enabled by default when building gdb-7.6.1 on OSX.

```
./configure --disable-werror
make
```

worked fine for me.

Answer (score 5):

The compiler is being overly picky, so it emits warnings for pointer arithmetic involving string literals. Also, you probably configured `gdb` with `--enable-werror` or `-Werror` is inherited from somewhere, thus these harmless warnings get turned into errors. (You only showed the configure flags for the compiler, not `gdb`.)

Solution: turn off `-Werror`, or silence this warning specifically using `-Wno-string-plus-int` (add to `CFLAGS`)

Comment: I try to install gdb thru ./configure then make then make install. I get the same error. So how exactly can I turn off -Werror?