# gdb seg faults when reading symbols

Tags: c++, debugging, memory, gdb

When trying to run gdb with a program, it seg faults while reading symbols.

When I run:

`gdb /home/user/path/to/program.exe`

I get:

```
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.7-0ubuntu3.1) 7.7
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from /home/user/path/to/program.exe...Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I suspect that the binary might be too large for gdb to load into memory. This error only occurs when I compile with -g (debug flag). Here's the difference in size of the binaries:

Compiled with

`-release flag: 405 MB`

`-debug flag:  862 MB`

Any ideas on other culprits of this segmentation fault? Or is there a way to increase the memory allowed for gdb? This turns out to be a very challenging problem to google.

Comment: Side note: Some office mates have suggested the solution to use gdb on gdb (is this even possible? - doesn't seem to work) or try lldb instead (looking into this now).

Comment: What compiler did you use ? Have you tried another gdb install ?

Comment: intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1. No, do you mean reinstall gdb, or install a different version? I can try that.

Comment: yes or try a gdb on another machine ?

Comment: I'll try to reinstall gdb, the program takes 4+ hours to compile and I don't have a debug version compiled on another machine. I'll get that started as well, but it will be a while.

Comment: Update: I did find an older debug version of the program installed on a different machine (3 years old), and it does run with gdb. It's binary is 937MB, which might mean that the binary size is not the issue.

Comment: So you might very well have a gdb that is not properly installed. You should try the exact same version on a different machine to be sure.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55021/discussion-between-rm-rf-and-quantdev).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you compile without the -g flag then you are not including debugging information in your executable, so when gdb loads there's much less information to load in.

If gdb segfaults during start up then this is a gdb bug, there's no executable that you should be able to pass to gdb that should cause a segfault, at worst you should get some error message.

You could try running gdb under gdb, (just do `gdb --args gdb /home/user/path/to/program.exe`) this will not help you much, but might give some insight into what is wrong with gdb, you could then file a gdb bug here: https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/enter_bug.cgi?product=gdb but this is only worth doing if you either have good steps to reproduce, or a backtrace from a crashed gdb.

Reinstalling gdb might help, but I wouldn't hold much hope of that solving the problem, unless you change the version of gdb you install, gdb itself is a pretty easy program to install, so pretty hard to get wrong.

You could also try building gdb from git, it's pretty easy, and the bug might have already been fixed, start from here: http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/current/

If you extend your question with a backtrace from a crashed gdb then others might be able to offer you more of an insight into why this is crashing, but the blame is definitely with your version of gdb.

Comment: The problem was fixed in the latest gdb update (7.8.1).

Comment: Same problem, not fixed with 7.8.1

Comment: had the same problem with gdb 7.9

Comment: fixed in gdb version 7.9.90

Answer (score 5):

I was having the same problem with `gdb 7.9` on `Ubuntu 15.04 x86_64`, which I had installed simply using `apt-get install gdb`.

I solved the problem by compiling and installing a previous version: `gdb 7.5.1`.

I had to download a library (which I found out [here](https://superuser.com/questions/489304/why-cant-i-find-termcap-library-when-i-build-gdb)) and I also had to run `./configure` using some arguments (which I found out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19367279/error-while-running-make-on-gdb-7-6-on-my-mac)). Everything else is straightforward.

Good luck.

Here are the commands:

```
$ cd
$ sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev
$ wget ftp://sourceware.org/pub/gdb/releases/gdb-7.5.1.tar.gz
$ tar zxf gdb-7.5.1.tar.gz
$ cd gdb-7.5.1
$ sudo ./configure --disable-werror
$ sudo make
$ sudo make install
```

Comment: For me 7.9.1 worked, while 7.12 and 7.7.1 were failing